# Replace source code with different source code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'm trying to build an artist website which has video uploaded in the website. I've used HTML 5 video to create a video player in my website. So, I've created a container for the video player and another wrapper for the video playlist. By default, the first video in the playlist will be played. In my playlist, I've added a play button, when you clicked at that button, then the source code from that section should be added in the video player's source code and the old source code should be removed and the new source code should play on the video player. I'm not sure how to replace the default source code with the new source code of the video.

Here is my markup for the video player:

```html
<div id="player" class="video">
  <video width="320" height="240" controls="" autoplay="">
    <source class="player-source" src="http://testsite.dev/files/playlist/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Here is my markup for the Video playlist:

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Play</th>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Save</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="play-pause">http://testsite.dev/playlist/video1.mp4</td>
      <td>Sample Company 1</td>
      <td><a href="http://testsite.dev/playlist/video1.mp4" target="_blank">Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="play-pause">http://testsite.dev/playlist/video2.mp4</td>
      <td>Sample Company 2</td>
      <td><a href="http://testsite.dev/playlist/video2.mp4" target="_blank">Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="play-pause">http://testsite.dev/playlist/video3.mp4</td>
      <td>Sample Company 3</td>
      <td><a href="http://testsite.dev/playlist/video3.mp4" target="_blank">Download</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my Js Code:

```js
$('.play-pause').click(function(){
  var $VideoURL = $(this).text(),
      $scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('source'),
      $currentScriptSrc = $scripts[$scripts.length-1].src;

  $scripts.removeAttr('src', $currentScriptSrc);
  $scripts.attr('src', $VideoURL);
});
```

I'm not sure how to make this work. I don't know what's wrong with my code or lacking with my implementation. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Remove $scripts.removeAttr('src', $currentScriptSrc); this line console what you are getting inside $VideoURL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to mix jQuery wrapped elements and vanilla elements. Try the following:

```js
$('.play-pause').click(function(){
    var videoURL = $(this).text(),
        $lastSource = $('source').last();

    $lastSource.attr('src', videoURL);
});
```

You could make this script more robust by assigning an ID to your source tag, so that you can retrieve it much more easily: `$source = $('#sourceId');`

Comment: Thank you. That works well and followed your opinion and looks the right thing.